# why is the outer for loop not completing?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, nested-loops

(output.getUpperBound(0) equals 6 by the way)
(rawString and rawAverage are just string arrays)

So, when i step through this code, the inner for loop does the full 6 cycles but as soon as the inner loop completes, the task finishes. what i am trying to achieve is the inner loop to perform 6 times, 6 times, and the outer loop to perform 6 times.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To output.GetUpperBound(0)
        For f As Integer = 0 To output.GetUpperBound(0)
            If rawString(x).Substring(2, 1) = rawString(x + f).Substring(2, 1) And rawString(x).Substring(0, 1) <> rawString(x + f).Substring(0, 1) Then
                If blnCheck Then
                    rawAverage(x) = rawString(x).Substring(1, 1) + rawString(x + f).Substring(1, 1)
                    blnCheck = False
                Else : rawAverage(x) = rawString(x + f).Substring(1, 1)
                End If
                'rawAverage(x) = rawString(x).Substring(1, 1) + rawString(x + f).Substring(1, 1)
                Label1.Text = Label1.Text + rawAverage(x)
                Label2.Text = Label2.Text + rawAverage(x + 1)
            End If

        Next

    Next
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code to indicate that the outer loop won't run 6 times.

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict`.  You are doing arithmetic on strings

Comment: Could be.  I might have been misled by the var name and operator used: `Label1.Text = Label1.Text + rawAverage(x)`   looks like it is accumulating a result   @JamesThorpe

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah - I removed my comment as I just realised this was VB as well, so ought to be `&`.

Comment: yeah the strings are concatenating. Just stepped through again and the outerloop performed one and a half times. Also i removed the + 1 (x+1) and the outer loop performed twice in total, quite confused

Comment: Are you sure you've posted your actual exact code?  Are you modifying the value of `x` anywhere?

Comment: How come "the outerloop performed one and a half times"? Loop can either perform or not perform; there is no "half" option.

Comment: because this code is inside a form load sub, so the form loads after x only equals 1. but actually maybe x is being set to something elsewhere that is good point i will test to see